# Why is my Python script writing Windows style carriage returns?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, fabric

I am trying to write a script that creates a fabfile, saves it and then runs it. Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

bakery_internalip = "10.10.15.203"

print "[....] Preparing commands to run within fabfile.py"

fabfile = open("sfab.py", "w")
fabfile.write("from fabric.api import run, sudo, task\n\n@task\ndef myinstall():\n\tsudo('yum install httpd')")
fabfile.close

print "Running Fab Commands"

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['fab', '-f', 'sfab.py', '-u ec2-user', '-i', 'id_rsa', '-H', bakery_internalip, 'myinstall'])
```

The contents of my fabfile are as follows:

```
[root@ip-10-10-20-82 bakery]# cat sfab.py
from fabric.api import run, sudo, task

@task
def myinstall():
        sudo('yum install httpd')
```

My script gives the following error when I run it:

```
Fatal error: Fabfile didn't contain any commands!
```

However, if I run dos2unix on the file and then run the following, it works fine:

```
 fab -f sfab.py -H localhost myinstall
```

Comment: It should also run after without dos2unix since the file is closed when process exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple typo `fabfile.close should be fabfile.close()`

Running without closing will give you:

```
Running Fab Commands

Fatal error: Fabfile didn't contain any commands!

Aborting

with open("sfab.py", "w") as fabfile:
    fabfile.write("from fabric.api import run, sudo, task\n\n@task\ndef myinstall():\n\tsudo('yum install httpd')")
```

Alway use `with` as above to open your files, it will automatically close them for you and avoid these simple errors.

Comment: This is the perfect example why the `with` syntax should almost always be used.

Comment: @DarinDouglass, you commented as I was editing. with is always the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running it on Windows.

When using `open(path, "w")`, Python uses the OS's native linebreak combo.

To use `\n` specifically use `open(path, "wb")`.

For more information see [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).